# How to set a label and UUID for the entire drive?

Tags: linux, partition, parted

I notice that some drives have label and UUID assiged on a drive level

```
$ lsblk -dno PATH,LABEL,UUID
/dev/sda SYSTEM 2019-02-12-05-40-19-00
/dev/sdb                               # No label & UUID
```

How can I set/change this value for /dev/sdb?
Both drives are GPT partitioned.

Answer (score 1):

Only if you format the entire drive as a filesystem as opposed to creating a partition table such as MS-DOS or GPT, you'll get a `UUID`.

The UUID lsblk reads is from partitions/filesystems.

Comment: /dev/sda in my example has GPT partitions, /dev/sda does not have a specific filesystem. Also it's not UUID but some kind of timestamp

Comment: Yes, a timestamp, not a UUID. This looks like a weird bug but I can't say where it comes from.